# Adding files to /usr/local/include

Tags: c, linux, go

I recently installed openjtalk on a linux machine, and I want to be able to wrap it in Go. The source files for openjtalk have several subfolders with different sources, which I assume are found by the compiler because of the make files.

Should I copy each of those sub-folders into `/usr/local/include`? Is that a "correct" way of fixing include dependencies. From what I tested, Go seems to find the included files if I copy them, but I'm not sure if this is the correct, linux way of doing things.

Comment: For example, gcc has a -I flag that when you `-I/your/new/headers`, you'd be adding this folder to the list of header directories. That's the way I've seen in many projects. It's also easier to setup a working environment to a new system.

Comment: This works. If you right as an answer I'll mark it as correct. Go also seems to required the include and cflags commented lines to be one line above the `import "C"` or else it doesn't work.

Comment: These requirements are documented. Please read the manual for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually not a good idea to change locations of external libraries. Some libraries automatically put themselves in include paths of compilers but for those that don't, adding their paths to the compilers' include paths is always a better idea.

For example, in gcc, you can `gcc -I/your/header/directory` to include your directory. Usually people put those info in the Makefile. This way, you can put external libraries' source code in your repository and just tell compiler to also look for the headers there. This way, when setting up a new working environment, all you have to do is pull from the repository.